# How can I change output format of Angular Boostrap datepicker?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

The Angular Bootstrap Datepicker is giving the format

```
Wed Nov 02 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Hora padrão de GMT)
```

How can I change to ?

```
2011-11-02
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="FetchCtrl"> 
     <input type="text" 
            class="form-control" 
            datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
            ng-model="data_inicial" 
            ng-change="updateUrl()" 
            is-open="opened" 
            datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
            date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
            ng-required="true" 
            close-text="Close" 
            /> 
            <span class="input-group-btn"> 
               <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
               </button>
            </span>
<h1>{{data_inicial}}</h1>
```

Thank you

Hugo

Comment: <div ng-controller="FetchCtrl">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="data_inicial" ng-change="updateUrl()" is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
       <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
        
  <h1>{{data_inicial}}</h1>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `date` filter like `date:'yyyy-MM-dd'`

In your case:

```
<div ng-controller="FetchCtrl"> 
     <input type="text" 
            class="form-control" 
            datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
            ng-model="data_inicial" 
            ng-change="updateUrl()" 
            is-open="opened" 
            datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
            date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
            ng-required="true" 
            close-text="Close" 
            /> 
            <span class="input-group-btn"> 
               <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
               </button>
            </span>
<h1>{{data_inicial | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</h1>
```

Other formats you can find <kbd>[here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3adate)</kbd>

For controller try:

**JS**

```
$scope.data_inicial = new Date();
// ....

  var date =  '0' + $scope.data_inicial.getDate();
  var month = '0' + ($scope.data_inicial.getMonth() + 1); //Months are zero based
  var year =  $scope.data_inicial.getFullYear();
```

$scope.fixedDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + date ;

Comment: Thank you very much. But if I want to have this value in the controller, not only in the view?

Comment: I am trying toLocaleDateString()

Comment: see my edit, didn't check syntax anyways this is a way

Answer (score 0):

Judging on [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/datepicker/docs#datepicker-settings), you may format using attributes, for example.